# Compute the radical of $\langle z-3x, z-\frac{3}{2}y\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals

I wish to compute the radical of the ideal $\langle z-3x, z-\frac{3}{2}y\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ (having worked with the Nullstellensatz Theorem to get here).

I presume the radical is the ideal itself, but do not know how to show it. I've tried to show the ideal is prime (not sure if it actually is prime but a prime ideal is always radical) and also tried applying the definition of the radical directly, having no luck.

Any tips would be great please!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed prime (hence radical), because the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$ which is an integral domain.

To check your understanding, construct such an isomorphism.

Comment: I think this uses what I'm trying to prove: presumably the map you're referring to sends $f(x,y,z)$ to $f(t,2t,3t)$? The problem with that is showing that the kernel is exactly our ideal; the aim of the question was to show that the ideal is precisely the set of polynomials which vanish at all points $(t,2t,3t)$ (i.e. I'm computing the ideal of the set $\{(t,2t,3t):t\in\mathbb{C}\} = V(\langle z-3x, z-\frac{3}{2}y\rangle)$, for which I used the Hilbert bases theorem to deduce it's the radical of the ideal in question, and now need to compute this radical.

Comment: In the quotient, the relations imply that there is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space basis consisting of powers of $z$, so I had in mind $g: \mathbb{C}[t] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/\langle z-3x, z-\frac{3}{2}y\rangle$ defined by $g(t) = z$.